# Hypernym for "business", "company", "organization", "institution"

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

Is there a hypernym for the following terms?

- *Local business*
- *Company*
- *Organization* or *institution*

### Edit

I am building a website where one can create a profile that will either be a Local Business, a company, an organization or an institution. 
At the moment I am using the general term `Profiles` but it does not sound very professional. I would like to stand away from the term Profiles if possible. I was also thinking about the term `Entity` but it's not very nice either..
Facebook is using the general term `Pages` (see [here](http://www.facebook.com/pages/create/)) but for them, a page can also be a brand, a cause, a community, etc...which is a bit different.

Comment: Is there a particular context you're looking to use this in?

Comment: Yes, we absolutely need context. Otherwise anything from *entity* to *noun* is a valid suggestion.

Comment: Many thanks @simchona and RegDwighT. I have updated my answer and tried to be as clear as possible. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you need to decide whether you want to talk about the pages on which the profiles are contained, the profiles themselves or the subjects of the profiles.  What is important to you here?

Comment: Thanks @Jim, I am talking about the profiles themselves.

Comment: Then there you go, call them *profiles* because while the profiles may be *about* companies, institutions, etc, that's not what you are talking about.

Comment: Before one looks for hypernyms, one should ensure that the hyponyms are well-defined or at least non-synonymous. I'm fairly sure that defined senses for business / company etc _do_ overlap.

Comment: An *organization* is anything that is organized. I'm not sure a hypernym would be very helpful; can't you use the term as it is?

Comment: As was already suggested, *"entity"* or *"organization"* can be used to describe any of the listed types of enterprises. Actually, *"enterprise"* would work also.

Comment: Honestly, in the world of PR, "profile" is probably the best word you're going to find. It gives a business a sense of humanity.

Answer (score 2):

The term which strikes me as the most apt for this is ***enterprise***.

Answer (score 1):

The term *business venture* is very general, but may be associated with risk or gambling. If it's clear from the context that no such undertaking is implied, then it may be applicable in your case.

Another useful word may be *operation*, but it is less formal in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

How about "corporate entity" or "business entity"?

EDIT: Based on TimLymington's comment (good one! I had missed this type of customer all together) and on the current lingo adopted by the likes of Facebook, I suggest "Homes" as in "The entity's Home on the web". "Home" is also a standard term for a website's landing page.

Comment: Government departments, churches or charities may need profiles, but would not be happy with these descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use *initiative*.

Answer (score -1):

For the specific application you are talking about, I would suggest:

*activity/organization*

That could be a good choice in the context of a website that aims at identifying the four entities: local business, company, organization or institution. Both a local business and a company are economic **activities**, because a local business is a specific type of [company](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/local-business.html) . An organization is most certainly an **organization**, and an institution *may refer to* an [**organization**](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/institution.html). So, website users will know that what they are searching for **could be** under *activity/organization*.

Comment: To make this a better answer, can you please expand on why this is a good choice?

Comment: Done. The pair activity/organization isn't a hypernym, but could be useful in this context. I specified it at the beginning of the answer, so to clarify what I'm trying to say there.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the word *entrepreneur*.

Comment: "Entrepreneur" always refers to a person; the question asks about a word which can be applied to companies and other types of organisation.