# What's collective term for clients, customers, students, donors or anyone who has a beneficial relationship with an organization?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, hypernyms

My clients offer services that can be used by different types of organizations: schools, nonprofits, corporations, individuals, restaurants, etc. If I want to talk to all of their ____ simultaneously in a marketing comm., how could I address them?

- What is the hypernym that encapsulates all these different types of organisations?

Comment: Related: [Hypernym for “clients”, “members” and “partners”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102247/hypernym-for-clients-members-and-partners) and [Hypernym for “business”, “company”, “organization”, “institution”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110683/hypernym-for-business-company-organization-institution)

Comment: Yes, you're looking for a hypernym, not a collective noun. And this has been addressed here before.

Answer (score 1):

[“Stakeholder”](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/stakeholder.html) would work for all the example organizations on your list except perhaps “individuals.”

**Stakeholder**

> A person, group or organization that has interest or concern in an
>   organization.
>     Stakeholders can affect or be affected by the
>   organization's actions, objectives and policies. Some examples of key
>   stakeholders are creditors, directors, employees, government (and its
>   agencies), owners (shareholders), suppliers, unions, and the community
>   from which the business draws its resources.
>      Not all stakeholders
>   are equal. A company's customers are entitled to fair trading
>   practices but they are not entitled to the same consideration as the
>   company's employees.

(from *Business Dictionary*)

Comment: As was posted in the duplicate. Twice.

Answer (score -1):

There are the terms symbiosis or symbiotic and mutualistic that refer to a mutually beneficial relationships.